# problem with connection from groovy script :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jenkins, jdbc, groovy

I am a beginner user in jenkins.
I wrote a pipeline that load a groovy script like this :

```
stage('Load') {
  code = load 'Myscript.groovy'
}
  stage('Execute') {
  def bodyText = code.MyMethod()
}
```

My script groovy need to connect on a SqlServer DB but when i try to build my pipeline this is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:565)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader.loadClass(CallSiteClassLoader.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.loadClass(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java_lang_Class$forName$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at Script1.AggiornaDBProjectDB(Script1.groovy:116)
```

I have other job groovy in my project that do connection at the same db without problem, can someone help me ?
below my code for the connection :

```
 def AggiornaDBProjectDB ( sqlUrl)
     {
      def dbDriver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      def user =  ""
      def password = ""
      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

      sqlUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://MyServer;instance=XXXXX;databaseName=YYYYY;integratedSecurity=true"
      def sql = Sql.newInstance(sqlUrl, user, password, dbDriver)
    // def sql = Sql.newInstance(sqlUrl)    
    }
```

Thanks in advance